# Firebase-Admin Install Statement for Python Mini

Tags: python, firebase

I have noticed that in order to use the firebase-admin library, you need to have an install statement like this:

```
pip3 install firebase-admin
```

This install statement does not work for python mini, and I have not found any other install statements that work.  Does anyone know an install statement for python mini?

I have searched different websites to try to find the correct install statement, but none of them work for python mini.